# Construct index/membership vectors from lists of items

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say you have the following baskets:

```
basket1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
basket2 = ['orange', 'grape']
basket3 = ['banana', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'orange']

baskets = [basket1, basket2, basket3]
```

And your goal is to create the following datastructure:

```
pd.DataFrame({'apple': {'basket1': 1,'basket2': 0,'basket3': 0 }, 'orange': {'basket1': 1,'basket2': 1,'basket3': 1 }, 'banana': {'basket1': 1,'basket2': 0,'basket3': 1 }, 'grape': {'basket1': 0,'basket2': 1,'basket3': 1 }, 'kiwi': {'basket1': 0,'basket2': 0,'basket3': 1 } })
```

Which looks like: [image]

I know there's `Counter` from Collections and `bincount` from numpy which you could leverage if you just wanted a binary list like the one above, but say you wanted to put some other value at each of these points:

For example, say that instead of a 1, at each point, you wanted to put the weight of the fruit, which you happen to have in another table:

```
pd.DataFrame({'weight': {'apple': 3, 'orange':3, 'banana':2, 'grape':1, 'kiwi':2}})
```

[image]

And the result you want is:

```
pd.DataFrame({'apple': { 'basket1': 3, 'basket2': 0, 'basket3': 0 }, 'orange': { 'basket1': 3, 'basket2': 3, 'basket3': 3 }, 'banana': { 'basket1': 2, 'basket2': 0, 'basket3': 2 }, 'grape': { 'basket1': 0, 'basket2': 1, 'basket3': 1 }, 'kiwi': { 'basket1': 0, 'basket2': 0, 'basket3': 2 } })
```

[image]

How would you go about writing such an operation cleanly? I'm not quite sure how to go about performing this operation efficiently or well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you start out with a `pd.Dataframe` and a `dict`:

```
In [37]: df1
Out[37]:
         apple  banana  grape  kiwi  orange
basket1      1       1      0     0       1
basket2      0       0      1     0       1
basket3      0       1      1     1       1

In [38]: mapper = {'apple': 3, 'orange':3, 'banana':2, 'grape':1, 'kiwi':2}
```

Then simply:

```
In [39]: for colname in df1:
    ...:     df1[colname] = df1[colname]*mapper[colname]
    ...:

In [40]: df1
Out[40]:
         apple  banana  grape  kiwi  orange
basket1      3       2      0     0       3
basket2      0       0      1     0       3
basket3      0       2      1     2       3
```

Or even more simply, you can intelligently mutiply a `pd.DataFrame` by a `pd.Series` (i.e. a "column" of a dataframe):

```
In [5]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'weight': {'apple': 3, 'orange':3, 'banana':2, 'grap
   ...: e':1, 'kiwi':2}})

In [6]: mapper = df2.squeeze() # convert to series

In [7]: df1*mapper
Out[7]:
         apple  banana  grape  kiwi  orange
basket1      3       2      0     0       3
basket2      0       0      1     0       3
basket3      0       2      1     2       3
```

Or starting from scratch:

```
In [8]: basket1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
   ...: basket2 = ['orange', 'grape']
   ...: basket3 = ['banana', 'grape', 'kiwi', 'orange']
   ...:
   ...: baskets = [basket1, basket2, basket3]
   ...:

In [9]: fruitvolume = {'apple': 3, 'orange':3, 'banana':2, 'grape':1, 'kiwi':2}
```

Then simply:

```
In [12]: data = [{item:fruitvolume[item] for item in basket} for basket in baskets]

In [13]: data
Out[13]:
[{'apple': 3, 'banana': 2, 'orange': 3},
 {'grape': 1, 'orange': 3},
 {'banana': 2, 'grape': 1, 'kiwi': 2, 'orange': 3}]

In [14]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[14]:
   apple  banana  grape  kiwi  orange
0    3.0     2.0    NaN   NaN       3
1    NaN     NaN    1.0   NaN       3
2    NaN     2.0    1.0   2.0       3
```

But now you'll have to do some munging...

```
In [16]: df = df.fillna(0).astype(int)

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   apple  banana  grape  kiwi  orange
0      3       2      0     0       3
1      0       0      1     0       3
2      0       2      1     2       3
```

Comment: Not bad, but is there something more general than a two-step solution like this?

Comment: @AlexLenail I added an even simpler solution, but as for a more general solution.

Comment: @juanapa.arrivillaga I like that last solution! I guess I didn't know pandas would do such a good job interpolating the NaNs, I thought it would just break. =)

Comment: @AlexLenail yup, pandas is pretty smart about this sort of thing